# Java Special character encoding issue

Tags: java, oracle11g, character-encoding, special-characters

I tried to insert some special character via java into oracle table and then retrieve it again--assuming my encoding will work.
Below is the code which i tried.

```
  String s=new String("yesterday"+"\u2019"+"s");
  ...

  statement.executeUpdate("INSERT into test1 values ('"+s+"')");
  ResultSet rs=statement.executeQuery("select * from test1");
  while (rs.next()) {
      System.out.println(new String(rs.getString(1).getBytes("UTF-8"),"UTF-8"));
  }
  ...
```

Now, when I try to see output via commandline execution it displays special character always: `yesterdayâ€™s`

My question is: why even after using encoding, it is not showing expected result. i.e. `yesterday’s`. Is above mentioned code is not correct or some modification is required?

P.S.: In eclipse, the code might result `yesterday’s`, but if executed via command line , it shows `yesterdayâ€™s`

I am using :

--  JDK1.6

-- Oracle : 11.1.0.6.0

-- NLS_Database_Parameters: NLS_CHARACTERSET WE8MSWIN1252

--Windows

**Edit**:

\u2019 : this is [RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm) & I am looking for this character only.

Comment: Never ever use concatenation in SQL queries. Use [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). Let the driver do all dirty work.

Comment: thanks @vsminkov for suggestion, its just for representation purpose, will not use it in actual code.

Comment: On Windows? You probably have set a different encoding in the console (`chcp` is your friend) than Java believes. But in this case, simply println `\u2019` should reproduce the issue as well.

Comment: yes, I am using windows

Comment: Why are you doing `new String(rs.getString(1).getBytes("UTF-8"),"UTF-8")`? This is exactly the same as just `rs.getString(1)`.

Comment: If you are seeing the right character in Eclipse but not in the command window, this means you have the wrong character set. At the command prompt (within a SQL\*Plus session) enter `$chcp 1252` and then try again, see if you can get the character displaying properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an illustration of what I suggested in a comment (change the character set of your client). Straight from my SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> select unistr('\2019') from dual;

U
-
Æ

SQL> $chcp 1252
Active code page: 1252

SQL> select unistr('\2019') from dual;

U
-
’
```

If this works for you, you may want to add `$chcp 1252` to your `[g]login.sql`.

Answer (score 2):

Check the java property "file.encoding" when you run on the commandline, it may be set to something other than "UTF-8" causing the text to display incorrectly when you output on the commandline.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the character encoding for the apostrophe is \u0027

I ran this in the command line:

```
public class Yesterday{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = new String("yesterday" + "\u0027" +"s");
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

it resulted in:

```
yesterday's
```

Comment: i edited question, \u2019 is RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK and i am looking for this character only.